# I don't get the right data. I just got random number

Tags: c++

My assignment is about arrays and structures. The first part that I need to do is read data from the input file. However, I'm stuck on that. I know that I got some random numbers. However, I can't find it. It took me one hour to find those mistakes. Can you guys please show me where I got it wrong? I'll appreciate it. Thank you!!!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

const int SIZE=15;

// Here is my structure declaration.
struct BestColleges
{
    int rnk;        // The rank of college.
    string name;    //The college name.
    int years;      // Which years did college establish?
    string email;   // The address of college.
    double TranferRate; // % of students who graduate and transfer
    double RetentionRate;   // % of students who first year retention.
    int low_cost;       // The lower cost of attendance
    int high_cost;      // The higher cose of attendance
    double numStudents; // how many students in the college.
};

void getData (BestColleges c[], BestColleges *plast);
void printCollege1 (BestColleges College[],BestColleges *plast);

int main()
{
    ifstream inputFile;
    int num_college;

    cout << " Welcome to my program!!! " << endl;

    BestColleges *College;
    College = new BestColleges[SIZE];
    BestColleges *ptr;
    BestColleges *plast = College+ SIZE-1;
    ptr= College;

// Here is my function definition
    getData( College, plast);
    printCollege1( College, plast);


  // I'm testing if I got the data from input file
//cout << num_college << endl;



    cout << " Thank you for reading my program! See you again!" << endl;

    return 0;
}
// Here is my fuction definition
void getData (BestColleges c[], BestColleges *plast)
{
    ifstream inputFile;
    int num_college;

    inputFile.open("CA_BestColleges.txt");
    inputFile >> num_college;

    for ( BestColleges *p =c; p < plast; p++)
        {
            inputFile >> p->rnk;
            getline(inputFile,p->name);
            inputFile >> p->years;
            getline(inputFile,p->email);
            inputFile >> p->TranferRate;
            inputFile >> p->low_cost;
            inputFile >> p->high_cost;
            inputFile >> p->numStudents;

        }
        inputFile.close();
}
void printCollege1 (BestColleges c[],BestColleges *plast)
{

    for ( BestColleges *ptr = c; ptr < plast; ptr++) // Here is my printing entirely information.
            {
                cout << " Rank: " << ptr->rnk <<  endl;
                cout << " Name: " << ptr->name << endl;
                cout << " Email: " << ptr->email << endl;
                cout << " Graduation and Transfer Rate: " << ptr->TranferRate << endl;
                cout << " First Year Retention Rate: " << ptr->RetentionRate << endl;
                cout << " Cost of Attendance: " << "$" << ptr->low_cost << " - " << "$" << ptr->high_cost << endl;
                cout << " Number of Students: " << " approx. " << ptr->numStudents << endl;
                cout << endl;
            }
}
```

Here is my input file:

```
15
Palo Verde College
1947
http://www.paloverde.edu
31.2 82.7 14266 18266 3898
4
Diablo Valley College
1949
http://www.dvc.edu
50.2 90.5 14839 20579 24781
6
Foothill College
1957
http://www.foothill.edu
68.8 87.5 12300 19302 18362
12
College of the Siskiyous
1957
http://www.siskiyous.edu
59.8 82.0 15306 21936 2473
10
Cuesta College
1963
http://www.cuesta.edu
50.7 86.2 12052 19135 9571
8
Ohlone College
1965
http://www.ohlone.edu
52.1 91.1 10898 15878 18000
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the input file?

Comment: How are you parsing the text file? By the way, here is not a place to ask your assignment questions but I would recommend that you ask a specific detail on your assignment question that can help you to work on your assignment.

Comment: I mean I know I got some trash number. However, I don't know where I got it wrong. I just want to ask where it is. I don't mean you need to fix it for me.  looking for it

Comment: Well in your comment we can't get the new lines so we don't know if the problem could be there. Another thing you might want to change is your loop condition `BestColleges *plast = College+ SIZE-1;` will make it stop one before the end. That would explain at least bad results on the last.

Answer (score 0):

You get bad results because you're not parsing correctly:

```
for ( BestColleges *p =c; p < plast; p++)
    {
        inputFile >> p->rnk;
        getline(inputFile,p->name);
        inputFile >> p->years;
        getline(inputFile,p->email);
        inputFile >> p->TranferRate;
        inputFile >> p->low_cost;
        inputFile >> p->high_cost;
        inputFile >> p->numStudents;

    }
```

You're missing `inputFile >> p->RetentionRate;`. Because of this the next items will read unexpected data and will cause bad results.

Answer (score 0):

You have a one-time read for the number of colleges, but it is not in the file, so a rank is read into that.  The rest of out of sync after that.